# MySQL Boot Failure | How to delete Db from Config?

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, innodb

I am having issues starting MySQL Community Server on my VPS. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with MySQL running on 5.7. What I understood from the error is that I had a database were it got removed from the folders in `/var/lib/mysql` However, It didn't get removed from the MySQL configuration. How can I remove it from MySQL configuration?
Here are Error Details:
When Starting MySQL: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)`
Systemctl status: https://hastebin.com/qibigatuta.sql
Log File in `/var/log/mysql`: https://hastebin.com/yecajibila.sql

Comment: There was a Database called `s1_bans` I deleted that, As the error shows that its unable to gain access to `s1_bans` old tables that are marked with Litebans in the log file. How can I delete this database from the MySQL configuration? Put in note that I don't have phpmyadmin.

Comment: I tried to create the directory and tables using `mkdr` and `touch` and this error started showing and the others disappear. 
https://hastebin.com/uzoluxevok.sql

Comment: Did you "delete" it with `DROP DATABASE`?

Answer (score 0):

you should use mysql cli client.
just run in the Linux shell:

```
mysql -uroot -p<your-password>
```

and then in the mysql shell run:

```
mysql> drop database s1_bans
```

But it seems that the error details you provided direct to other problem which is either:

1. MySQL is not running so there is no socket file to connect to. (Most likely)
2. The socket file is in another directory and you need to use:

   ```
   mysql -uroot -p<your-password> -s <path/to/your/socket/file>
   ```

in order to connect locally to your mysql server.

Comment: MySQL is not running so there's no socket file to connect to, What shall I do in this case

Comment: I tried to Create the database again using `mkdr` and `touch` and this error started showing: https://hastebin.com/uzoluxevok.sql

Comment: You should manage MySQL only by using MySQL commands. use: create database s1_bans. and then create tables using create table statement.  Using mkdir or touch is not recommended.

Comment: If the DB is not running use: **systemctl start mysql** to start it.